# Short proof (trig function)

Tags: trigonometric-series

Prove that $\sin^2x=1/2(1-\cos(2x))$ is true for every $x \in \Bbb R$.

Useful information: $\cos(2x)=\cos^2x -\sin^2x$

Comment: Hint: $1=\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}$.

Comment: This is one of the linearisation formulæ in trigonometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that $sin^{2}(x) + cos^{2}(x) = 1$ and $cos(2x) = cos^{2}(x) - sin^{2}(x)$, we have

$$1 = cos^{2}(x) + sin^{2}(x) \Rightarrow$$ 
$$1 - cos^{2}(x) = sin^{2}(x) \Rightarrow$$
$$1 - (cos(2x) + sin^{2}(x)) = sin^{2}(x) \Rightarrow$$
$$1 - cos(2x) - sin^{2}(x) = sin^{2}(x)\Rightarrow$$
$$1 - cos(2x) = 2sin^{2}(x) \Rightarrow$$ 
$$sin^{2}(x) = \frac{1-cos(2x)}{2}$$

Comment: I dont get how you get from $1-(cos(2x)+sin^2(x)) = sin^2(x)$ to $ 1-cos(2x) = 2sin^2(x)$

Comment: @QWERTYZ use that $ 1 - (cos(2x) + sin^{2}(x)) = 1 - cos(2x) - sin^{2}(x)$.

Comment: Switching algebraic signs when removing brackets, i suck lol. Thank you very much though.

Comment: why the down vote? Is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}{2}$$

$$=\frac{\sin^2(x)+1-\cos^2(x)}{2}$$
$$=\frac {1-(\cos(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\sin(x))}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: From the given formula, you deduce, with *Pythagoras*, the other two standard formulæ:
$$\cos 2x=2\cos^2x-1=1-2\sin^2x,$$
whence the linearisation formulæ.